# How to use pandas at?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am often confused about pandas slice operation, for example,

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts'], 
    'company': ['1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd', '1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd','1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'], 
    'name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze', 'Jacon', 'Ryaner', 'Sone', 'Sloan', 'Piger', 'Riani', 'Ali'], 
    'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 2, 3],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'company', 'name', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])

def get_stats(group):
    return {'min': group.min(), 'max': group.max(), 'count': group.count(), 'mean': group.mean()}
bins = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]
group_names = ['Low', 'Okay', 'Good', 'Great']
df['categories'] = pd.cut(df['postTestScore'], bins, labels=group_names)
des = df['postTestScore'].groupby(df['categories']).apply(get_stats).unstack()
des.at['Good','mean']
```

and I got:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last) pandas/_libs/index.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
>
> TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 des.at['Good','mean']
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
>   **getitem**(self, key)    1867     1868         key = self._convert_key(key)
>   -> 1869         return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)    1870     1871     def **setitem**(self,
>   key, value):
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   _get_value(self, index, col, takeable)    1983     1984         try:
>   -> 1985             return engine.get_value(series._values, index)    1986         except (TypeError, ValueError):    1987
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> KeyError: 'Good'

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the line,

```
des = df['postTestScore'].groupby(df['categories']).apply(get_stats).unstack()
```

after doing a group by over 'postTestScroe' you are getting **"Series"** not **"DataFrame"** as shown below.

[image]

Now when you are trying to access scalar labels with DataFrame des **".at"** it doesn't recognize label 'Good' since it doesn't exist with Series.

```
des.at['Good','mean']
```

Just try to print **des** print,you will see the resulting series.

```
           count   max   mean   min
categories
Low           2.0  25.0  25.00  25.0
Okay          0.0   NaN    NaN   NaN
Good          8.0  70.0  63.75  57.0
Great         2.0  94.0  94.00  94.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working due the Categorical Index:

```
des.index
# Out[322]: CategoricalIndex(['Low', 'Okay', 'Good', 'Great'], categories=['Low', 'Okay', 'Good', 'Great'], ordered=True, name='categories', dtype='category')
```

Try changing it like this:

```
des.index = des.index.tolist()
des.at['Good','mean']
# Out[326]: 63.75
```